# Can you refactor column or table names in Azure SQL DataWarehouse with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, azure-synapse

With SQL DB projects in Visual Studio, I can easily right click on table or column names and it provides an option to rename them, and then provides an opportunity to apply the name change to all other SPs, views etc which reference that table/column. However, with SQL DataWarehouse tables, this option does not seem to be available. Does anyone know if I am missing something, or if there is a workaround to help refactor the code?
Thank you.

Comment: Paging @KevinNgo...